# Spring Boot - Any exception in @RestController returns 403 - even if I throw a 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

EDIT:

The fix for me for this was to re-do the configuration for Spring Security - I'm not exactly sure what fixed it but the old config I was using did not work with the new Spring.

So, I really just started over with the new docs and re-wrote my config methods for Spring Security.

END EDIT

I have a Spring Boot app - newly updated version of Spring Boot - that started returning 403 to my client no matter what the REST controller throws. I have this:

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
fun getAllUserData(@RequestParam("start") start: Long = 0, @RequestParam("end") end: Long = 2684276745101): List<UserLog> {
    throw(NotFoundException())  // Method works without this line
    return userLogMapper.findFirst(maxRows, start, end)
}

@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
class NotFoundException : RuntimeException()
```

When I call this method with an authenticated user, my client gets 403 and I see this in the debug:

```
2023-05-24T20:21:23.285-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-05-24T20:21:23.286-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?start=1672549200000&end=1684974082325
2023-05-24T20:21:23.287-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-24T20:21:23.287-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-24T20:21:23.288-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-24T20:21:23.288-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-24T20:21:23.288-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-05-24T20:21:23.289-04:00 DEBUG 134852 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

How do I get the 404 to work? I have other exceptions that are acting the same way (I throw a 500, client gets 403 back).

I suspect it's something with Spring Security being updated to 3.0.6

Security config:

```
package com.saisols.survey.config

import com.saisols.survey.dao.ConfigMapper
import com.saisols.survey.dao.UserLogMapper
import com.saisols.survey.spring_beans.JWTAuthenticationFilter
import com.saisols.survey.spring_beans.JWTAuthorizationFilter
import com.saisols.survey.spring_beans.JWTService
import com.saisols.survey.spring_beans.SurveyUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
// @EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) Don't enable yet...
// Found more than one annotation of type interface org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize attributed to public java.util.List
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102645/annotationconfigurationexception-since-upgrade-to-spring-boot-3-jdk-17
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class BasicWebSecurityConfigAdapter{
    @Autowired
    lateinit var jwtService: JWTService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var suds: SurveyUserDetailsService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var encoder: PasswordEncoder

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userLogMapper: UserLogMapper

    @Autowired
    lateinit var configMapper: ConfigMapper

    var twoFaEnabled: Boolean = false

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(
        authConfig: AuthenticationConfiguration
    ): AuthenticationManager {
        return authConfig.authenticationManager
    }

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity, authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager): SecurityFilterChain {
        twoFaEnabled = configMapper.findByKey("survey.2fa_enabled")?.configValue!!.equals("true")
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/login-state").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/verify-code").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
//                .httpBasic()
            .addFilter(JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager, jwtService, suds, twoFaEnabled))
            .addFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, jwtService, userLogMapper))
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        //http.cors().disable()
    return http.build()
    }

    /*override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.userDetailsService(suds).passwordEncoder(encoder)
    }*/

}
```

As suggested - I added `.requestMatchers( "/error").permitAll()` and now get this:

```
2023-05-24T20:58:21.678-04:00 DEBUG 140108 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?start=1672549200000&end=1684976301369", parameters={masked}
2023-05-24T20:58:21.678-04:00 DEBUG 140108 --- [io-8081-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-24T20:58:21.683-04:00 DEBUG 140108 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-05-24T20:58:21.684-04:00 DEBUG 140108 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Wed May 24 20:58:21 EDT 2023, status=403, error=Forbidden, path=/user-log}]
2023-05-24T20:58:21.689-04:00 DEBUG 140108 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

Comment: Check your authorization, it's very likely `hasAnyRole('ADMIN')` is the cause

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm logged in with a role of ADMIN (I'm calling a dozen other endpoints and if they don't throw an exception they are fine)

Comment: In fact, if I don't throw the NotFoundException the method works fine

Comment: Can you show your security configuration?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is caused by the `/error` page being under the control of Spring Security.  The 404 was properly thrown, and I'm going to assume that you don't have any ControllerAdvice defined for handling the 404, so you go redirected to the default error handler page, which is `/error` and handled by the `BasicErrorController`.  There's a line in your logs just above that redirect that says something like setting SecurityContextHolder to anonymous.  So, your authentication is being cleared from the SecurityContext and you're being redirected to a page under lock and key, hence the 403.

Try adding `/error` to your list of permitAll methods and see if you get through.  Then it's just a matter of tuning your security configuration to suit your needs.

Comment: I did that (see my edit) and I get a different error. Not sure that my client is following redirects (I don't think it is and curl without following redirects does the same thing)

Comment: Than you very much. It solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and of all the alternatives listed in [this very helpful overview](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-return-http-status-codes-in-a-spring-boot-application/), I could initially only get this one to work: wrap the return type in `ResponseEntity<T>`:

```java
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<UserDetail> getAllUserData(@RequestParam ...) {
    ....
    if (userDetail == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserDetail>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<UserDetail>(userDetail, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Workable, but seems a bit ugly to have to change your method return types - though one could also argue that this is only fair: we *are* implementing a REST controller, and an entity plus statuscode is exactly what REST methods should return.

However, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76328395/2109137) gave me the hint for how to solve this while sticking with `@ResponseStatus` and `ResponseStatusException`.

What appears to be happening is that Spring Boot, upon handling your exception, forwards control to an error dispatcher, for which the authenticated user is not authorised. The `403 FORBIDDEN` we see is the result of that.

This can be solved as follows in your `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        ...
        .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
            .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).authenticated()
            .requestMatchers(...)           // or on your methods
            .anyRequest().authenticated())  // or denyAll() if all requestMatchers are above
        ...
```

Thus permitting access to the error dispatcher.

Update: I just noticed [this relevant warning](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html) in the javadoc for `@ResponseStatus`:

> **Warning:** when using this annotation on an exception class, or when setting the reason attribute of this annotation, the `HttpServletResponse.sendError` method will be used.
>
> With `HttpServletResponse.sendError`, the response is considered complete and should not be written to any further. Furthermore, the Servlet container will typically write an HTML error page therefore making the use of a reason unsuitable for REST APIs. For such cases it is preferable to use a `ResponseEntity` as a return type and avoid the use of `@ResponseStatus` altogether.

This argues against using `ResponseStatusException` altogether, though I wonder if this advice still applies to a modern day `@RestController`. I could imagine that *"the Servlet container will typically write an HTML error page"* no longer necessarily holds, esp. under Spring Boot.

**Update (again)**

[This post](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) confirms my last point: Spring Boot 5 handles `ResponseStatusException` correctly, with its default whitelabel error page preempting the Servlet container's handling (provided you keep `server.error.whitelabel.enabled` at its default `true`).

You'll still need the `.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).authenticated()` in your filter chain.

You may want to set `server.error.include-message=always`, if you need your exception message to go back to the client. By default, the `message` field in the response entity is omitted for security reasons.

Finally, there's also `server.error.include-stacktrace` and `include-binding-errors` to get the full monty.

**Update (last one)**

After some testing it seems that this:

> You'll still need the `.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).authenticated()` in your filter chain.

is true only if your filter chain ends with an `anyRequest.denyAll()`. Apparently, the thrown exception is considered a mismatch, and the deny kicks in with a forward to the `ERROR` dispatcher.

So, with request matching in the chain, this is how to make it work:

```java
    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).authenticated()
        .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        ...
        .anyRequest().denyAll())
```

Or alternatively, replace the `denyAll()` with `authenticated()` and you can omit the `ERROR` authorisation:

```java
    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
        .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        ...
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
```

Which has the additional advantage that it also works for method security.  You couldn't have that `denyAll()` there (it would make all your methods unreachable) unless you precede it by a (broader) `requestMatcher`.

In fact, if you work strictly with method security, then simply this will do:

```java
    .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
```

which I believe is the default anyway, so can be omitted altogether.

Answer (score -1):

I was setting up my new springboot project from scratch and was facing same issue.

As mentioned by @lane.maxwell in previous answer -
Adding `/error` to my security config worked for me. It was related to spring security mapping all exception to `/error` and since `/error` was managed by spring security - default response behaviour is `unauthorized` (403).

I updated my spring-boot-3 security configuration like below and it worked :

```
...
authz.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll();
...
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - I'm updating my spring boot version, not starting from scratch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).